# Bookdown preview_chapter() not working with knit button

Tags: r, bookdown

I'm currently helping a professor build a data science book for his course, [Gov 50](https://www.davidkane.info/files/gov_50_fall_2020.html), at Harvard. The issue we're having while working with the `bookdown` package is that we cannot seem to build individual chapters with the `knit` button and preview the chapter automatically in a new window.

The error we get is:

```
Error in files2[[format]] : 
  attempt to select less than one element in get1index
Calls: <Anonymous> ... render_book -> setdiff -> as.vector -> source_files
Execution halted
```

So instead, we are forced to use the `preview_chapter()` function and then manually go through every html file for the book to find the chapter we want to preview. This ends up being time consuming and makes the process difficult for our individual chapter writers. Does anyone know what might be causing the issue?

Our _output.yml file seems to be setup correctly:

```
bookdown::tufte_html_book:
  df_print: default
  css: style.css
  split_by: "section"
  config:
    toc:
      collapse: subsection
      scroll_highlight: true
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems that this error is caused by specifying the order of Rmd files to build. The chapters can be previewed if I comment out this in my _bookdown.yml:

```
rmd_files: 
#  html: ["index.Rmd", ..., "references.Rmd"]
```